# How can I pass an image ID from the view into my routes.py, when the images are displayed in the view via a for loop?

Tags: flask

I'm building a simple portfolio website where the owner will be able to manage a gallery page, Adding, Editing and Removing posts. I am printing the images from the DB using a for loop and need a way in order to get either the name of the image or the ID of the image and send the value back to the route in order to delete the row from the DB. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Additional information:
**Using Flask w/ SQLalchemy & WTforms**

Sample of how I'm displaying the images and accompanying data:

```
    {% for image in Posts | reverse %}
    <div class="row pt-3">
    <div class="col">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="static/gallery_images/{{image.image }}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row pt-4">
    <div class="col">
        <h3 style="display: inline">{{image.title}}</h3>
        <p class="font-italic text-muted" style="display: inline">
            {% if image.sold_flag %}
            - Sold
            {% else %}
            - Available
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <p class="text-muted">{{image.date_posted.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p class="font-weight-normal">{{ image.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="col text-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<hr class="border">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to store the `id` and use it for a route call. Using purely what you have shared, you can add a call to the button to the respective endpoints:

Assuming you have a method `images.delete(id)` to delete images and that you want to keep with the `button` tag on your code:

```html
<a href={{url_for('delete.edit', id=image.id)}}>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
    Delete
  </button>
</a>
```

However, I would really recommend for you to use a form to submit the `delete`, as opposed to a `GET` request generated above. This way you can have it secured with WTForm CSRF token.

Example:

**HTML**

```html
<form action="{{url_for('delete.edit', id=image.id)}}" method="POST" role="form">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
</form>
```

**Python**

```py
## Make sure to create the delete form

class DeleteImage(Form):
    pass
```